# .NET Core 6 + Blazor: How to call server while only passing data in the uri

Tags: blazor-webassembly, asp.net-apicontroller

My question is about how to do the following with .NET Core 6 Blazor. If I knew how to simply make Blazor send some URI to the server, I would just do so, but I don't. I have googled for this quite extensively, but not found an answer.

I want to modify a single property of a record stored in a table. The server should load the data record with the given id, increment or decrement a counter stored in it, and save the record. There is no need to send the data to the client, have it modify the data, and have it send the modified data back to the server. Basically I am trying to model kind of RPC with Blazor.

So I want to make a call to my .NET Core 6 Blazor server, only passing a parameter in the URI (the ID of the database record to be modified).

Is there a method I could call that doesn't require a content parameter like PostAsync() and PutAsync() do? Right now I am doing this:

```
    public static async Task<bool> AddReference (Guid ID)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = 
            await httpClient.PostAsync(Routes.WatermarkApi + $"AddReference/{ID}", null);
        return (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

passing null for the content parameter, but this looks a little awkward to me.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The whole purpose of POST and PUT is to create or modify a resource with some content. It's not a Blazor quirk, that's the very definition of the HTTP verbs. Using an empty content is an exceptional case, which is why there's no default value for `content`

Comment: I want to modify a single property of a record stored in a table. The server should load the data record with the given id, increment or decrement a counter stored in it, and save the record. There is no need to send the data to the client, have it modify the data, and have it send the modified data back to the server. I just couldn't find any method allowing me to do this other than PostAsync with null as content data parameter. I would easily know how to do this directly with HTTP, but not how to do that with Blazor.

Comment: `There is no need`. The content doesn't have to be an object, especially with POST. [PUT](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#PUT) specifically means the resource will be replaced by the payload but [POST](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#POST) sends a payload whose handling is up to the server. [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789.html) does *exactly* what you want - modify just a few properties of a resource.

Comment: The problem with Blazor's PostAsync() is that all of its overloads require a content parameter. Doesn't Patch require me to send delta information? I just want to to read the data server side, modify one if its properties, and write it back. The desired operation is coded in the route (URI) sent to the server, which maps the call to the corresponding method of the corresponding controller.

Comment: You're describing an RPC call. HTTP isn't an RPC protocol. I already explained that yes, you can use POST with an empty payload but that's exceptional, which is why there's no default value for that parameter.

Comment: So how I understand you is that basically there is no Blazor method doing exactly what (or having exactly the interface) I was looking for, but Post with a null content parameter does the trick.

Comment: As for PATCH, by itself it doesn't specify what its payload will look like. There's [JSON Patch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for this, but ASP.NET Core requires JSON.NET to support it

Comment: My question was about how to do this with Blazor, which adds a host of stuff happening between the code you typed and what's actually being executed on the client. If I could (or knew how to) resort to sending a plain HTTP uri with Blazor, I would just do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245179/discussion-between-razzupaltuff-and-panagiotis-kanavos).